# strip leading and trailing newline characters in xslt

Tags: xslt

I have a xml with structure like this:

```
<xxx>
<yyy>
some text   with spaces inside
</yyy>
<zzz>
another text
</zzz>
</xxx>
```

I want to generate html that will be formatted with white-space:pre style, but I must remove the newline characters from node yyy and zzz.

My output should be something like this:

```
<div><div>some text   with spaces inside</div><div>another text</div></div>
```

I've tried

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

but it didn't work. The newline characters are still there.

I can't use normalize-space because the whitespaces between the words are important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Because you only want to remove the first and last characters from the string, this simpler transformation does exactly this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="yyy/text() | zzz/text()">
   <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,2, string-length() -2)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<xxx>
<yyy>
some text   with spaces inside
</yyy>
<zzz>
another text
</zzz>
</xxx>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<xxx>
<yyy>some text   with spaces inside</yyy>
<zzz>another text</zzz>
</xxx>
```

**Do note**: In a more complicated case you might want to strip-off all leading whitespace and all trailing witespace.

This can be done if you use the **[`trim()`](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-trim.xsl?revision=1.1&view=markup)** function/template from **[FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)**:

Here is a demo of using `trim()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:import href="trim.xsl"/>

  <!-- to be applied on trim.xml -->

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    '<xsl:call-template name="trim">
        <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="string(/*)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>'
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<someText>

   This is    some text   

</someText>
```

**the wanted (trimmed) result is produced**:

```
'This is    some text'
```

Answer (score 3):

The following XSL removes all newline characters from elements `yyy` and `zzz`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/xxx">
<div>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="yyy | zzz">
<div>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'&#x0d;&#x0a;', '')" />
</div>  
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You are right, the code above removes ALL newline characters. That's not exactly what I needed.